# KK-theory by abelianized correspondences of smooth stacks?

Tags: cohomology, higher-category-theory

Whith (Kasparov, bivariant) [KK-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KK-theory) I am left with the nagging feeling that the theory is "more fundamental", than has been made explicit, that there is a "more profound" universal characterization still to be uncovered.

This feeling is particularly driven by the characterization of certain KK-groups as abelianizations of [correspondences](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/correspondence) of spaces, as recalled [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KK-theory#ReferencesInTermsOfCorrespondences). Since "most" $C^\ast$-algebras arise as [topological/smooth groupoid convolution algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid%20algebra) an evident open question here seems to be the following:

*Shouldn't KK-theory have a neat characterization in terms of an abelianization/stabilization of [correspondences](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/correspondence) of [differentiable stacks](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differentiable+stack)?*  In particular if we allow at least the correspondence spaces themselves to be more general [smooth groupoids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth%20groupoid), maybe?

Put this way, this seems to suggest another question:

*Should KK-theory be thought of as an incarnation in topology/differential geometry of the same general principle which in algebraic geometry produces [motivic cohomology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivic%20cohomology)?*

Because in both cases one builds abelianizations of correspondences of the relevant "spaces".

Looking around, I see that Grigory Garkusha recently seems to talking about something at least very similar sounding, [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motive#RelationToKKTheory), though I still need to really absorb this.

Maybe here is another way to look at what I am after:

for $\mathbf{H}$ a [cohesive infinity-topos](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohesive%20%28infinity,1%29-topos) and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the [(infinity,n)-category of spans](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity,n%29-category%20of%20spans) $Span_n(\mathbf{H}, \flat \mathbf{B}^n U(1))$ in $\mathbf{H}$ over the coefficient object for $n$-localized action functionals is -- as recalled and discussed at *[nLab:prequantum field theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/prequantum%20field%20theory)* -- the codomain for (topological) local prequantum field theories

$$
  \exp(i S) : Bord_n \to Span_n(\mathbf{H}, \flat \mathbf{B}^n U(1))
  \,.
$$

For $n=2$ we have some results (indicated/announced briefly at the end in the examples-section of *[Higher geometric prequantum field theory](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Higher+geometric+prequantum+theory)* ) that show that the quantization of such a prequantum field theory wants to land in KK-theory, as a "geometric" improvement of the 2-category [2Mod](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2Cn%29-module) of bare algebras and bare bimodules. In view of the partial characterization of KK-theory in terms of just equivalence classes of precisely such spans [above](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KK-theory#ReferencesInTermsOfCorrespondences), this makes me wonder:

might the quantization of $\exp(i S)$ be just the postcomposition with a kind of stabilization functor  that sends spans/correspondences in $\mathbf{H}$ to their motivic/KK-theoretic abelianization?

For the case of discrete geometry, hence $\mathbf{H} = \infty Grpd \simeq L_{whe} sSet$, this idea or something close is appears in [Baez, Hoffnung Walker](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.4305) (for 1-groupoids) and at least roughly also in [Freed-Hopkins-Lurie-Teleman](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Topological+Quantum+Field+Theories+from+Compact+Lie+Groups) (for general $\infty$-groupoids). But I am after the geometric case here:

Doesn't it look like KK-theory wants to be the answer to "What is the abelianization of spans of [smooth groupoids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth%20groupoid)?" ?

What is known? What can one say? What seems likely?

Comment: I'm interested in the categorical meaning of KK-theory too. Unfortunately I don't know the answer.

Comment: Did you ever get any insight into this?